# How does a PHP page retrieve form data?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am new to PHP and am taking the PHP course on [W3Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools). In the form handling part of the course, I read that there are two methods of handling form data: [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) and [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). I understand that depending on the method used, a superglobal variable is created which stores the data as key-value pairs. And at the destination page, the data is retrieved from this variable (using `$_POST["key"]` or `$_GET["key"]`).

But my question is: Where is the superglobal variable (`$_POST` or `$_GET`) stored? If it is on that same page on which the form exists, how can it be accessed by another destination page specified in the `action` attribute of the `form` tag?

Is it that the same set of these superglobal variables are accessible by all the pages on the server (contrary to my present belief that **each** page has its own set of those)?

The code below should make my question more clear:

#### File *index.php*

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

#### File *welcome.php*

```
<html>
<body>

    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

W3Schools explains as follows:

> When the user fills out the form above and clicks the submit button, the form data is sent for processing to a PHP file named "welcome.php". The form data is sent with the HTTP POST method.
> To display the submitted data you could simply echo all the variables.

How do the variables `$_POST["name"]` and `$_POST["email"]` reach *welcome.php*?

Comment: Post is usually from a form.  Get is usually from a URL string.  That's what I always thought...

Comment: I wouldn't think so. If you send certain `_$POST` parameters to one script, e.g. `first.php`, the same `_$POST` data shouldn't be exposed to a different file (e.g. `second.php`), unless they're `require`'ing each other or something

Comment: The $_POST or $_GET arrays are stored in RAM for the page request, so only accessible to the instance of the page called by the request.

Comment: POST is stored on the page, and GET is stored on the link of the page where you determined the action to be on the form itself.

Comment: @ChrisSprague If that is the case, how can the `second.php` display the form data entered in `first.php`?

Comment: @ag_dhruv chris was referring to first.php as in first is displaying the form data entered.

Comment: @ag_dhruv likely because POST/GET data collected on one page may be, in turn, re-POST/GET'ed to the next page. Each page does have its own individual instance of these super globals.

Comment: @jessica Yes. So if `$_POST` is stored on the page (i.e. `index.php`), how does `welcome.php` access and echo `$_POST["name"]` and `$_POST["email"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a request to a web server (i.e. apache, nginx), the request is parsed into pieces to be understood. Then, in PHP's case, the file requested is sent to the PHP interpreter with the data from the request.

In your example, you want a form to send a POST request to the page `welcome.php`. (If you're new to requests methods GET/POST/etc, then w3schools has a simple explanation on that: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) Your form has the method set to `post`, this can be `get` but it generally never is. If a user pressed a submit button within a  tag, then the form sends to the request to the page set in `action` using the method set in `method`. Your form will send a `POST` request with the data name="..." and email="...".

When this request reaches PHP, all data sent to it will be stored in the method global variable. All post request place their data in $_POST, all get requests place their data in $_GET.

So when you submit your forms `POST` request, the page `welcome.php` will be requested by your browser (Firefox/Chrome) using the method `POST` and sending the data `name` and `email` in that request. On your server, PHP will open the file `welcome.php` and place the data into the $_POST array. Then, since $_POST is global, anywhere within `welcome.php` will have access to this variable.

If you manually go to the page `welcome.php`, you will be performing a `GET` request. Generally, only way to send a post request is through a form. So manually going to that page will have $_POST set to an empty array.

When I was learning PHP, I almost always had these lines at the top of the page so I knew what was going on:

```
<pre><?php print_r($_GET);?></pre>
<pre><?php print_r($_POST);?></pre>
```

This will print out the arrays in a pretty format, and the  tags will make sure they're formatted correctly in the browser (since print_r uses newline characters, and browsers ignore those unless in pre tags).

You could also swap `print_r` with `var_dump` to get way more info about the variable.

This is a simple answer, there's way more to web technologies. And once you understand PHP enough I'd move into frameworks like CakePHP or CodeIgniter which takes away a lot of the little bits. It's important to understand the basics first though.

Comment: Fantastic. So, in short, `index.php` sends `POST` request to the server with the form data in its body. The server opens `welcome.php` and places the data in the `$_POST ` array, which I then use to `echo` the data. Am I wrong anywhere?

Comment: @ag_dhruv, technically you should never display/use raw data. So yes the value is available in $_POST, you should validate/sanitize the data before displaying it or inserting it into a database.

Answer (score 3):

[Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) do not refer to the lifetime of a variable, but the scope in which the variable can be accessed.

[Session variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) can be accessed by other pages.

Also, regarding your comment "If that is the case, how can the second.php display the form data entered in first.php?"

first.php should save data to a database. second.php should read data from the database. If you are very new, I would suggest looking in to MySQL as a database. It plays very well with PHP.

Comment: To extend Chris' response. Both sessionStorage and localStorage can be used to pass data from one page to the other.

sessionStorage will only store the data locally until you close the tab while localStorage is more persistant and will store the data on the local machine indefinitely.

Unless there is a specific need for indefinite data storage on a users local machine, sessionStorage should be used.

Comment: This does not involve a database. Please refer my latest edit.

Comment: @ag_dhruv index.php is posting the variables to welcome.php. In index.php, you will see the action tag. That defines where index.php will send it's form variables when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your edit:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
```

The `method="post"` bit means that when the user hits "Submit" (or whatever triggers `action="welcome.php"`) the data will be collected from the `form` element and sent as POST data to the action target -- since it's a php file, you can then access this data through the superglobal, `$_POST`, as you've noted.

The `name` property in each of the `input`s inside the `form` sets the key for each element of the POST data that is sent, and whatever the user entered in the `input` will be the corresponding value to that key.

For instance, if the user entered "foo" for the `name`, and "bar" for the `email`, your `$_POST` data in `welcome.php` should look something like:

```
Array
(
    [name] => foo
    [email] => bar
)
```

Comment: Great! So, the data entered in `first.php` is stored in the superglobal array (`$_POST`) **of the action target** `welcome.php`. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure if "action target" is the exact proper description for this, but, yes, that sounds correct. I imagine if you changed it to `method="get"`, then you'd see this data populated in `$_GET` in `welcome.php` (rather than `$_POST`).