# Undefined array key in PHP for CRUD application

Tags: php, arrays

I am taking a intro course to database design and am new to php. I am doing a database class final project and I'm currently trying to create a CRUD for my database. I am doing the create.php to add new school programs. Note that I am using a template I found  on https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-crud-application.php.

**error when trying to enter a new program:**

> Warning: Undefined array key "programID" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\studentadvisor\create.php on line 14
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "pname" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\studentadvisor\create.php on line 24

**portion of code:**

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $programID = $pname = "";
    $programID_err = $pname_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    
    
    // Validate id
    $input_programID = trim($_POST["programID"]);
    if(empty($input_programID)){
        $programID_err = "Please enter a ID.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_programID, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $programID_err = "Please enter a valid program ID.";
    } else{
        $programID = $input_programID;
    }
    
    // Validate Name
    $input_pname = trim($_POST["pname"]);
    if(empty($input_pname)){
        $pname_err = "Please enter a name.";     
    } else{
        $pname = $input_pname;
    }

// Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($programID_err) && empty($pname_err)){
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO program (programID, pname) VALUES (?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_programID, $param_pname);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_programID = $programID;
            $param_name = $pname;
            
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
         
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Program</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="mt-5">Create Program</h2>
                    <p>Please fill this form and submit to add a program to the database.</p>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>ID</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($programID_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $programID; ?>">
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $programID_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <textarea name="address" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($pname_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $pname; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $pname_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2">Cancel</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've so far only deleted certain fields I won't be using for my database table and changed the variable names to those of my own table (programID, pname).

Comment: Not related to your problem, but try to be more consistent with your variable names, your future-self will thank you. Presumably "pname" is a "program name". You are already using "programID", and I'd recommend following one pattern or another. Personally I'm more partial to verbose names, `programId` and `programName`, or `program_id` and `program_name`.

Comment: By itself, `$_POST["programID"]` presumes that the key exists, which is not a safe assumption. You can `isset` or `??` to get around that: https://3v4l.org/BsWuf#v8.2.6

Comment: Specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685637/how-does-a-php-page-retrieve-form-data#:~:text=The%20name%20property%20in%20each%20of%20the%20inputs%20inside%20the%20form%20sets%20the%20key%20for%20each%20element%20of%20the%20POST%20data%20that%20is%20sent